# outofmemoryexception with large data

Tags: dataset, out-of-memory

In my application there is a SqlDataAdapter which fills a DataSet. The DataSet gets only one table and this table further gets only one DataRow. This DataRow has a colum which gets image data from datebase, so it could be very larg image data from data base.

```
SqlCommand cmd = DBHandler.CreateSPCmd("AttachmentSelectbyID");
DBHandler.AddParam(cmd, "@AttachmentID", SqlDbType.Int, attachmentID);
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Attachment");
```

The command throws an outofmemoryexception when the respective image data is very larg. I tried to use SqlDataReader, but the same exception happens still:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    object ob =  reader["AttachmentImage"];
}
```

The problem is not the larg number of data records, but I think the problem is based on very larg image data from data base. Is there any solution?

Comment: Why not provide details of the exception and the size of the image you think is the cause?

Comment: already fixed or you question can be deleted?